# Can we retrieve the parameters originally passed in scheduler.Schedule() (Like Args) in RQ scheduler?

Tags: python-3.x, scheduler, rq

## What i want:

I am trying to retrieve the parameters i passed to my job in rq scheduler while scheduling like:
args passed, Function name, and other things

#### What i have already tried:

```
list_of_jobs=scheduler.get_jobs()
# print("jobs lsit",list_of_jobs)

for job in list_of_jobs:
    print(job.args)
```

#### Error Shown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
 
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ile "/home/munz/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 266, in _deserialize_data
    raise DeserializationError() from e
rq.exceptions.DeserializationError
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are "Models aren't loaded yet"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685959/why-are-models-arent-loaded-yet)

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak No this is models for pickle that arent loaded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer to this is NO IT CANNOT BE DONE

#### Any job related parameters can only be retrieved using job ID so i suggest to keep the job ID stored for all your jobs else you will in darkness about their original parameters (when you set it)